# Editing own content for content type giving me access denied

Tags: users

For content type "XYZ" for a user that has "Edit own XYZ" content I get an access denied message when attempting to edit content that was created by user. Do I need any further access permissions? I can delete and view my own content, just not edit.

Answer (score 4):

The "input format" on the body field might be set to one that you don't have access to, example  "Full HTML",  "PHP", etc.

Check that you (your role) has that access. Look here: "admin/settings/filters"

If you don't have access to the "input format" used on the body field then you can't edit that content.

I recently ran in to something close to this, I was surprised to find this as the solution. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try rebuilding permissions @ admin/reports/status/rebuild

Verify user is the author of the node.

Verify user has role that has Edit Own XYZ permissions.

Comment: Tried all 3 suggestions and it is still giving me access denied. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem (after DAYS of work) by disabling the  “Domain content type” module.

To diagnose the issue, I had to enable the possibility to view the callback functions (which often bear the name of the module) in the trace the PHP code in `/var/www/synthesys/public_web/include/menu.inc` in the `function menu_executive_active_handler($path=NULL) (line 336):`

1) I replaced

```
if($router_item=menu_get_item($path)) {
```

with

```
if($router_item=menu_get_item($path)) {
  print_r($router_item)
```

...and...

2) replaced

```
else {
  return MENU_ACCESS_DENIED;
}
```

with

```
else {
  return call_user_func_array($router_item['page_callback'], $router_item['page_argument']);
  //return MENU_ACCESS_DENIED;
}
```